# How to move to another View by button using a SwiftUI - swift 5.5

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

For Example, This a view:

```
struct ContentA: View {
var body: some View {
   Text(“Hello”)
    }
}

struct ContentB: View {
var body: some View {

Button("Lets Go!") {
         // Here i wanna to move to ContentA view   
        }
    }
}
```

I want a way to reach the ContentA View by the button.

like this photo:[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KunfS.gif)

Comment: Code to Move? [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) You will encounter several solutions throughout. It is unclear what specifically you are trying to achieve. There are several ways to display other views.

Comment: Sheet -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(ispresented:ondismiss:content:) 
Full Screen -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fullscreencover(ispresented:ondismiss:content:)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this with SwiftUI is `NavigationLink`. I have tested this solution to work. You can also show a View as a Sheet. I'd look here for that solution. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-present-a-new-view-using-sheets

I believe the `NavigationLink` solution requires you to have `NavigationView` as well.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentA: View {
var body: some View {
    Text("Hello")
    }
}

struct ContentB: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        NavigationLink("Link to A", destination: ContentA())
        }
    }

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentB()
    }
}
```

Comment: i want it like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KunfS.gif

Answer (score -2):

You can do this via this simple call to the specific view you want to reach . If you want to reach contentAView then just call it in the buttons action space like so

```
struct ContentA: View {
    var body: some View {
       Text("Hello")
        }
    }
    
struct ContentB: View {
    @State var showContentA = false
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView{
            Button("Lets Go!") {
                showContentA = true
                
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showContentA) {
            ContentA()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code buys you a "Result of 'ContentA' initializer is unused" error.

Comment: yes , I can see that now , The answer should be fixed